# app that auto-generates CRUD UI for database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, perl, user-interface

I have a MySQL database that has a few very simple tables.

I would like to find an app (implemented in Perl, Python or PHP) that will do the following:

1. Point the app to a database table, and it automatically retrieves the table's schema from the database.
2. It then generates an HTML view of the table's data.  The data is displayed as a grid, with all fields being user-editable.  If there are a lot of rows, then it automatically provides pagination.
3. Bonus points for allowing the user to click a column heading, which would then sort the data by that column.
4. Bonus points for allowing the data to be filtered by a "where" clause.

I have already looked at a few packages (phpMyAdmin, webmysql), but they do not seem to provide the editable table view.  They seem more oriented towards database administrators.  What I need is something that's more oriented towards someone who wants to view, enter and modify data.

Comment: @Galen: It might have to do with the fact that Mike W seems to want turnkey solutions to complex problems. @Mike W: What you are looking for requires wiring together a lot of components: Something like `DBIx::Class`, a template engine and some JavaScript module to provide the UI.

Comment: Actually, there is a java solution for exactly this problem that very recently came out called naked objects . http://www.nakedobjects.org

Comment: @Sinan-Unur: I just need something really simple.  I don't need the UI to support fields that are references to other tables.  All I want is to edit the "flat" fields (e.g. ints, varchars, timestamps).  Since nothing seems to do exactly what I want , maybe I'll spend a few days and try to roll my own solution and post it back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, but none of those exactly fit the bill, so I decided to implement it myself.

The result is a new open source project called DWI, which stands for Database Web Interface.  It took me about 3 days to get it working, and I did it in about 600 lines of PHP and javascript.

If you want to check it out, it's located at http://code.google.com/p/dwi.

Comment: This link is dead now

Answer (score 4):

Use [phpGrid](http://phpgrid.com). This is all you need.

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid(“SELECT * FROM orders”, “orderNumber”, “orders”);
$dg -> display();
```

Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if Java NakedObejcts is what you want. http://www.nakedobjects.org

Comment: It looks cool, but the server I'm using has Perl, Python and PHP, but no java.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use groovy then [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) can get you jump started. It will build an ORM of your entire DB, build views and your basic CRUD is all built in.

If you have a real aversion to anything thats Java-based then perl's [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) can help build all your mappings but might not get you the whole 9 yards. You will need to write some of your basic CRUD, which is easy and can be accomplished by simple following the Catalyst [tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.8002/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial.pod).

Answer (score 0):

Use **[CakeApp.com](http://cakeapp.com)**, it does exactly what you want!

> CakeApp.com is a rapid development online tool. It's easy to use, no
>   other software than your browser is needed. Benefit from ER-Diagrams
>   of others and share your visions too.

Comment: HOLLY SMOKES! I likee! Thanks man, I bet you I've across it and had no idea what I was looking at!